# Vim NERDTree re-size vsplit

Tags: linux, vim, command-line, vim-plugin

I am using the NERDTree plugin for Vim. When using the `s: open vsplit` command, is it possible to resize the windows so that the file is taking up a larger portion of the screen than the directory tree?

[**EDIT 1**]

I have attached a screeshot of my split view using NERDTree:
[image: NERDTree Screenshot]

I have installed NERDTree to ~/.vim

[**EDIT 2**]

I do not appear to have ~/.vimrc. I have included a screenshot of /etc/vim/.vimrc

[image: /etc/vim/.vimrc]

Answer (score 0):

You should give more context, like paste your .vimrc and add a screenshot because (what I understand is) the behaviour you want is AFAIK NERDTree's default behaviour.

The only situation I can imagine where a new vertical split would be smaller than NERDTree is when you already have a bunch of vertical splits and Vim is adjusting their width to accomodate the new one.

Comment: I have attached a screenshot. to got to this I am simply navigating to a file and then typing `s` for split view.

Comment: Please post your `~/.vimrc`: some settings may cause that.

Comment: I do not appear to have ~/.vimrc. I have attached a screenshot of /etc/vim/.vimrc. I hope that helps.

Comment: Does `/etc/vim/vimrc.local` exists? If yes what is its content?

Comment: No it doesn't. Under `/etc/vim` I have `vimrc` and `vimrc.tiny`

Comment: I don't have a `debian.vim` file in `/etc/vim`. `vimrc` and `vimrc.tiny` are the only files in the directory.